# Latex problem with \today

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

I have a problem with the `\today` statement in Latex.
As you can see below I'm getting the wrong result for the German date format which would be 17. November 2016.

The `gloss-german.ldf` defines it in the right order:

```
\def\date@german{%   
\def\today{\number\day.%
  \space \ifcase\month%
  \or\if@austrian@locale Jänner\else Januar\fi\or Februar\or März\or%
  April\or Mai\or Juni\or Juli\or August\or September\or Oktober\or%
  November\or Dezember\fi
  \space \number\year}%
}
```

You may try his with the following code:

```
%!TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german} 
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
    \begin{document}
        German (\textgerman{Deutsch \today}) 
    \end{document}
```

Here my output:

[image]

Thanks for your help and sorry for my English.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get the correct date with XeLaTeX and an error with LuaLaTeX (undefined `\luatexpardir`, package `luatex85` does not help).

Comment: I tried this with two different computers and it did't work. Strange.
I tried now with TeXworks and recieved the correct date but in Texstudio it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek luatex commands are enabled unprefixed so it'll be `\pardir` something needs updating...

Comment: This might due to `bidi`. Can you tell what version of it you have?

Comment: Where do I find this information @egreg ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. `\let\luatexpardir\pardir` and `\let\luatextextdir\textdir` are needed to get it compiled for LuaLaTeX. The date is correct. Version of package `polyglossia` is 2015/03/25 v1.42.4. Version of package `bidi` is 2016/05/03 v19.2.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `grep '\\luatex' /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luabidi/*`

Comment: @Mathnix In the log file

Comment: This ist what I found:

* bidi package (Bidirectional typesetting in
* plain TeX and LaTeX, using XeTeX engine)
* 
* Description: A convenient interface for
* typesetting bidirectional texts in plain TeX
* and LaTeX. The package includes adaptations
* for use with many other commonly-used packages.
* 
* Copyright (c) 2009--2016 Vafa Khalighi
* 
* 2016/05/23, v19.6

Comment: @egreg oddly enough that's exactly what I did:-)

Comment: @Mathnix Try updating, the current version is 20.3

Comment: Im not able to update MikTex...  i will try to install it again.

Juhu it is working. Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was solved by a software update